# Evaluate an expression into a given environment

Tags: r

I would like to call a function inside a given environment so that the execution of the function does not mess the global environment. I have something like that:

```
f <- function() { x <<- 5 }
e <- new.env()
evalq(f(), envir = e)
```

I want to evaluate `f()` inside the environment `e`, but it seems it does not work since the variable `x` is accessible from the global env instead of the env `e`. I mean I want to access `x` by typing `e$x`, not `x`.

I tried to build the function `f` inside `e` like this:

```
e <- new.env()
evalq(f <- function() { x <<- 5 }, envir = e) 
evalq(f(), envir = e)
```

But it still does not work, `x` is in the global env, not in `e`.

---

EDIT with more informations:

From the answers I received, I understand that `<<-` should not be used. The problem is that, in practice, I don't know what `f` is, since it is obtained by sourcing a file which is downloaded through a shiny app. The purpose of this app is to evaluate a classifier function `f` written by students. So in case they used the `<<-` operator in their function, I don't want to pollute my global env (which seem to be impossible from the description of the `<<-` operator).

I think I could remove the potentially created variables with something like

```
vars <- ls()
evalq(f(), envir = e)
new_vars <- ls()
rm(list = new_vars[!new_vars %in% vars])
```

But is there a better solution?

Comment: Simplest solution: don't use `<<-`. I you *must* use this operator for some unknown reason, then construct an object of the same name in the inner environment first. From the help file (`?"<<-"`): *The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment.*

Comment: Thank you, but I do not control if `<<-` is used or not. I added some more informations in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `assign` to define the environment where the object should be created:

```
e <- new.env()
f <- function() {
    assign("x", 5, envir = e)
}
f()

x
# Error: object 'x' not found
e$x
# [1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

As @lmo says, the simplest way would be to not use `<<-` to do this. Also, the function runs in its own environment so if you were to use `<-` you would need to assign the output of the function to a variable (otherwise it is only created in the `f`'s temporary environment. Something like this would work:

```
f <- function() { x <- 5 }
e <- new.env()
evalq(x <- f(), envir = e)

e$x
#[1] 5
```